# Django add objects to Related Manager during creation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider a simple ForeignKey relationship:

```
class A(Model):
    pass
class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A)
```

I have an API view that creates an A and a set of B's based on outside data (data NOT passed from the user), then serializes the created objects and returns the serialized data. My object creation code looks something like:

```
a = A()
a.b_set.bulk_create(B(a=a) for b in [...])
```

My issue is that this does not add the B objects to a's b_set, so that if I were to run

```
print(a.b_set.all())
```

afterwards, it would re-query the DB to get b_set. This is unnecessary though, because I already have a's entire b_set as I just created it. I'm doing this with a series of nested objects so it results in a LOT of unnecessary queries. My current workaround is to, after creation, run a query like

```
A.objects.prefetch_related('b_set').get(a=a.id)
```

then serializer that fetched object. This limits serializtion to just one unnecessary query, but I'd like to eliminate that one as well. It seems to me like there should be a way to cache the created B objects on a, and eliminate 
any need to hit the DB again during serialization.

Comment: Why don't you reuse the list of created objects that is returned after executing `a.b_set.bulk_create(B(a=a) for b in [...])`?

Comment: I'm calling `bulk_create` from within create in a serializer (let's say `ASerializer`), which returns an `A`. Then, I'm using a different serializer for A (let's say `ASerializer2`) to serialize `a`, which is what's doing the extra query. As far as I know there's no way to directly pass `a` and the created `B`'s to the second serializer, which is why I'm trying to cache them with `a` in some way.

Comment: I can suppose you still need to get object id's, which are not present in your "just created b_set",  so you need a db query for that,  and this is the logic behind Django making the query again.

Comment: BTW,  if you call a.b_set.all() twice in a row,  you will still have two queries. Django won't  cache it unless prefetch related is used

Comment: do u mind sharing view&serializer code?

Comment: I'm actually using Postgres, so `bulk_create` does return IDs. I'm going to look into the source and see if I can force it to cache the objects the way `prefetch_related` does, I'll report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation into the `QuerySet` and `Model` source code, I decided my best/only option was to directly modify `_prefetched_objects_cache` on each object. Definitely not pretty but it works. Here's the gist of what I did:

```
a = A()
b_set = a.b_set.bulk_create(B(a=a) for b in [...])
a._prefetch_related_cache = {}
a._prefetch_related_cache['b_set'] = b_set
```

This ensures that all the created B's are cached on `a`. Note that if `B` has an auto-created primary key field, those fields won't be populated in the objects returned by `bulk_create` with most backends. Fortunately I'm using PostgreSQL which returns auto-PKs from `bulk_create` so that's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to first execute `a.save()` before you can `bulk_create`.  Here are my results using the two models you described:

```
a = A()
a.save()
a.b_set.bulk_create([B(a=a), B(a=a), B(a=a)])    
a.b_set.count()
>>> 3
```

Comment: That still does an unnecessary query to the DB though. I'm using the Django debug toolbar, and I can see that it does any extra select on the DB to get the count value.